# store encoded files into container format

Tags: android, video, synchronization, containers, video-encoding

I'm trying to implement a Video Compressor in android using the Media Codec API,

I've successfully decoded a file into raw format and encoded it & getting different encoded tracks (Video, and Audio's ). How to store these files into a container format? Is there any in built functions available to do the same.

How to synchronize the audio, video and subtitles files ?

Comment: .mp4 or .3gp (since i used avc, 3gpp codecs )

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.3 (API 18) added the [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class.  This allows you to convert the raw H.264 video stream to a .mp4 file, optionally merging an audio stream in.

Each frame of data is submitted with a presentation time stamp.